# How to solve warning: received 'true' for non-Boolean attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import {close, logo, menu} from '../assets';
import {navLinks} from '../constants';

const Navbar = () => {
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <nav className="w-full flex py-6 justify-between items-center navbar">
   <img src={logo} alt="hoobank" className="w-[124px] h-[32px]" />
    
    <ul className='list-none sm:flex hidden justify-end items-center flex-1'>
      {navLinks.map((nav, index)=>(
        <li
         key={nav.id}className={`font-poppins font-normal cursor-pointer text-[16px] ${index === navLinks.length - 1 ? 'mr-0' : 'mr-10'} text-white mr-10`}
         >
          <a href={`#${nav.id}`}>
            {nav.title}
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>

    <div className="sm:hidden flex flex-1 justify-end items-center">
      <img 
      src="{toggle ? close : menu}
      alt= "menu 
      className="w-[28px] h-[28px] object-contain"
      onClick={() => setToggle((prev) => !prev)}
      />
      <div
      className={`${toggle ? 'flex' : 'hidden'} p-6 bg-black-gradient absolute top 20 right-0 mx-4 my-2 min-w-[140px] rounded-xl sidebar`} 
      >
        <ul className='list-none flex flex-col justify-end items-center flex-1'>
      {navLinks.map((nav, index)=>(
        <li
         key={nav.id}className={`font-poppins font-normal cursor-pointer text-[16px] ${index === navLinks.length - 1 ? 'mr-0' : 'mb-4'} text-white mr-10`}
         >
          <a href={`#${nav.id}`}>
            {nav.title}
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

[not able to render menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWwX5.png)

Comment: welcom to stackoverflow. You forgot to explain the problem, add more details and point to the line where the error occurs.

Comment: its showing warning Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `menu`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: menu="true" or menu={value.toString()}.
    at img

Comment: You can edit your question and add any extra information for people to see.

Comment: Include errors *as text*, not images. also, looks like either a bad copy/paste or some basic syntax errors around `src="{toggle ? close : menu} alt= "menu`?